# Plotting a variable in a Legend - Matlab

Tags: matlab, legend

Hi I am trying to plot a legend using a combination of text and variables.

I did some research and found that sprintf can be used, however I am having trouble implementing it.

My current code is

```
 legend('Type 1','Type' sprintf('%f',Type/4));
```

'Type' (the variable) is currently set to twenty, so I am trying to get the label to read 'Type 5'. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write it like this:

`legend('Type 1', sprintf('Type %i', Type/4));`

If the type is an integer, use `%i` instead of `%f` or else you will get `Type 5.00` (although you could explicitly tell it not to by specifying `%.0f`).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the native concatenation feature of array definition with `[]` and `num2str`:

```
legend('Type 1', ['Type ' num2str(Type/4, '%i')]);
```

Best,